# Combinatorics: Arrangement of 12 students along 2 rows with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

**QUESTION:**

Two variants of a test paper are distributed among 12 students. Number of ways of seating of the students in 2 rows so that the students sitting side by side do not have identical papers and those sitting in the same column have the same paper is:__________

**MY SOLUTION:**

Considering the two sets of paper be A and B. Then the 2 papers can be distributed among the students represented by the given two cases.

**Case 1**:

ABABAB

ABABAB

Students with set 1 can be seated in 6! ways. Similarly, students with set 2 can be arranged in 6! ways.

**Case 2**:

BABABA

BABABA

Students with set A can be seated in 6! ways. Similarly, students with set B can be arranged in 6! ways.

Total permutations=2∗6!∗6!

But the answer given is 2∗12!
Although, I know the reasoning behind the correct answer but I want to know where the mistake is in my approach.

Comment: Do we know ahead of time which six students get test $A$?  Could any choice of six students get test $A$?  Multiply your answer by $\binom{12}{6}$ to decide who gets test $A$ and recognize that $\binom{12}{6}=\frac{12!}{6!6!}$ and see the cancellations.

Comment: In addition to the comment of @JMoravitz, which I agree with, your posting seems to have a typo.  In Case 1, the second row should $$\text{also be} ~\color{red}{\text{ABABAB}}.$$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks! Got my answer it seems actually the question was supposed to be asking for both selecting and seating the students. Then the answer would be 2 × 12! but the question only specifies seating the students. So, in that case my answer (2×6!×6!) is correct.

Comment: I disagree.  The phrasing as presented here should be read as "*selecting and seating*" as you call it.  That is to say, we don't know ahead of time who gets what type of test.

Answer (score 1):

$$1-3-5-7-9-11$$

$$2-4-6-8-10-12$$

Lets assume that we numbered all $12$ desks in the class where $(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10),(11,12)$ are adjacent desks.

Now , we have $12$ students to place them $12$ distinct places , we can do it by $12!$ ways. When it is come to dispersing test variants, there are two cases such that :

Start dispersing test variants such a way that :

- The student sits in desk $1$  takes variant $A$ , the student sits in desk $2$ takes variant $B$. The rest arranged with respect to them
- The student sits in desk $1$  takes variant $B$ , the student sits in desk $2$ takes variant $A$.The rest arranged with respect to them

So , $2 \times 12!$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

- Imagine the $12$ permuted in a line in $12!$ ways
  with tests in ABAB/BABA sequence
- Cut the line into half, and put  half  in the $2nd$ row, thus $2\cdot12!$